# MySQL syntax error on "" (blank) - UPDATE query

Tags: php

Below is my PHP code but instead of updating data it is giving me following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2**

I tried everything but nothing is working.

```
<?php
    include 'includes/connection.php';

    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE student SET `name`='$_POST[name]' , `email`='$_POST[email]' , `dob`='$_POST[dob]' , `phone`='$_POST[phone]' , `college`='$_POST[college]' , `address`='$_POST[address]' , `state`='$_POST[state]' , `country`='$_POST[country]' WHERE id = $_POST[id]") or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>      
        Student has been modified! <br/>
        <a href="index.php">Go to MAIN MENU</a>
```

The same query is working with different fields on the same server. But I don't know what is wrong with this.

Comment: Separate out the `mysql_query` from the actual string (i.e. do `$sql = 'UPDATE ...'` and then feed it to MySQL separately). Then, echo `$sql` to see what you get, and let us see it. I suspect PHP is having problems reading `$_POST[name]` - although `{$_POST['name']}` would be more likely to work, either syntax is a serious security problem (SQL injection), so you should separate these variables out and make them safe beforehand.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_* statements as they are deprecated. USe mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: If I were to guess, it would be all similar to `='$_POST[name]'`. My guess is, it should probably read as `=$_POST['name']` etc., including `$_POST[id]`. I'm learning myself, but am reading as much on the subject as I can, till I'm "good and ready" to move forward ;-)

Comment: Have you echoed out the query you're generating? Does it look like you expect?

Comment: "To post an answer or not to post an answer, that is the question". Would Shakespeare been a good blogger in this day and age, *you think*? Since the OP is not interacting, I've answered William's question, and the answer is **"no"**. *Not going there*.

Comment: check if your fields have not null set..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your query is a single line, yet the error is at line 2**

Your code is not safe, you are not sanitizing the values and the error comes from this fact. `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated for this kind of mistakes.

Your code has a logic problem as well: you want to process changes if the user *submitted* information to the server, but your conditional `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` says **if not set** thus tries to update information when it should not.

#### Using PDO (assuming connection was successful)

```
include 'includes/connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE student SET `name`=:name , `email`=:email , `dob`=:dob , `phone`=:phone , `college`=:college , `address`=:address , `state`=:state , `country`=:country WHERE id = :id");

    $statement->execute(array(
        ':name' => $_POST['name'],
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':dob' => $_POST['dob'],
        ':phone' => $_POST['phone'],
        ':college' => $_POST['college'],
        ':address' => $_POST['address'],
        ':state' => $_POST['state'],
        ':country' => $_POST['country'],
        ':id' => $_POST['id']
    ));
}
```

#### Using `mysql_*` functions

```
include 'includes/connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $college = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['college']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
    $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

    /**
     * For debugging purposes
     */
    $query = "UPDATE student SET `name`='$name' , `email`='$email' , `dob`='$dob' , `phone`='$phone' , `college`='$college' , `address`='$address' , `state`='$state' , `country`='$country' WHERE id = '$id'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    /**
     * For debugging purposes
     */
    echo "<pre>Last query: $query</pre>";
}
```

Notice that `$id` should either:

- be escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string` and use quotes inside the query
- or converted into an int with `intval` (assuming is a numeric index)

Comment: ok your "Using mysql_* functions" is working fine and I am not getting any error but data is still not modifying. The reason I was using !isset was it was not going in the if statement. So just to check I put the ! sign and it was going in if statement now. What is the problem over here ?

Comment: Maybe the `$_POST` variable doesn't contain what you expect

Comment: `!isset` means **when is not set**, `isset` means **when it is set**. Which one do you need?

Comment: I checked $_POST also and it is displaying correctly. For example, Array ( [name] => 6666 [email] => 3333 [dob] => 2011-11-11 [phone] => 3333 [college] => 3333 [address] => 3333 [state] => 3333 [country] => 3333 ) Student has been modified! 
Here I modified name 3333 by 6666 in the form

Comment: You are right it should be isset that is what I used in my previous project but that is not working here :|. I am working on same server, still!

Comment: `$_POST` doesn't have `id`. You need to send `$_POST['id']` too

Comment: Thanks for letting me concentrate on id. Finally able to fix the problem. The problem was when I was updating the data I wasn't updating the id as that has to be set during the creation only. And therefore when I was modifying data I was not doing anything to id. I should have thrown it to modify page anyways. And one more thing I had to do. As I was passing it to next page instead of submitting, I had to use $_GET['id'] instead of $_POST['id']. Code works like a charm now :D

Answer (score 0):

Wow, wow, wow! You're not validating any data and using mysql_query(). It's easy to attack your server by SQL injections!

Try PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

**Back to topic:**

please show us the content of $_POST:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and the full SQL string:

```
$sql = "UPDATE student SET `name`='$_POST[name]' , `email`='$_POST[email]' , `dob`='$_POST[dob]' , `phone`='$_POST[phone]' , `college`='$_POST[college]' , `address`='$_POST[address]' , `state`='$_POST[state]' , `country`='$_POST[country]' WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
echo $sql;
```

The SQL looks not that good. Actually you've to output $_POST values like this:

```
$_POST['name']
```

Please do yourself a favor and use PDO! :-)

**Edit 1:** Escaping example:

If you don't want to use PDO, try at least this way:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE student 
            SET `name`    = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) ."', 
                `email`   = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) ."', 
                `dob`     = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']) ."', 
                `phone`   = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']) ."',
                `college` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['college']) ."',
                `address` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']) ."',
                `state`   = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']) ."',
                `country` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']) ."' 
          WHERE id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
```

Comment: no $_POST['name'] is giving me syntax error so I am sure it has to be '$_POST[name]' as I used the same query somewhere else and it was working fine.

Comment: @KunalMawar Of course you get an error, because: quotes inside a quote doesn't work without escaping!

Comment: @KunalMawar Look at my example. That should work for you.

Comment: Thnx for all the help I was able to solve my problem. It was me only doing silly mistakes :/. I posted the reason above and how I fixed it. How noob of me :|

Comment: @KunalMawar: Making mistakes is okay if you don't do them twice! ;-)